# How to use complex custom adapter with Asynctask and load to Recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask

I am trying to develop an app, that has Facebook like News Feed, on its MainActivity. When the custom adapter was not complex, it was loading all the posts fast and never hanged. But now when the custom Adapter becomes complex it loads all posts so slowly and hangs. I want to manage all custom adapter method with Asynctask class to faster the result. **I read the Android developer guide also there are two other classes, one is the future task and one another with it. I also read the loader but I didn't get it. I don't care if you can solve my problem using all those or Asynctaks. THANK YOU**

I tried many answers from StackOverflow, but I didn't get it.

**Here is my Asynctaks: below List mUserPosts that is List of model class methods or items and List Keys are declared in MainActivity and also instaniated with new operator.**

```
    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<List<Posts>, Void, Boolean>
{


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(List<Posts>... posts) {

        Query sortPostInDescendantOrder = PostsRef.orderByChild("counter");

        sortPostInDescendantOrder.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                mUserPost.clear();

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Keys.add(dataSnapshot1.getKey());

                        Posts posts = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Posts.class);
                        mUserPost.add(posts);
                    }


                      PostAdapter postAdapter = new PostAdapter(mUserPost, Keys, MainActivity.this);
                      postList.setAdapter(postAdapter);
                      progressCircular.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                      UserStatusButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                    else {

                      /* Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no post Exists! " + DatabaseError.PERMISSION_DENIED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         progressCircular.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         UserStatusButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); */
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {

        if (success)
        {
            //I checked from here also but nothing happened so commented it.
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+ Keys, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //PostAdapter postAdapter = new PostAdapter(mUserPost, Keys, MainActivity.this);
           // postList.setAdapter(postAdapter);
           // progressCircular.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           // UserStatusButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
          //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no post Exists! " + DatabaseError.PERMISSION_DENIED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          //  progressCircular.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           // UserStatusButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

**All I want is, how to manage the below custom adapter with Asynctask, Where to declare that Asynctask for managing the below custom adapter to faster my app:**

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference LikesRef, CommentsRef, ShareRef;

DatabaseReference SCommentRef, SLikesRef, SshareRef;

private boolean LikeChecker = false;
private boolean ShareChecker = false;

private static int TYPE_POST_PHOTO = 0;
private static int TYPE_TEXT = 1;

List<String> keyList;
List<Posts> List;
Context context;
private String CurrentUserID, GlobalPostKey;
private String statusUserID, tobevisitprofileId;

public PostAdapter(List<Posts> list, List<String> keys, Context context) {
    List = list;
    keyList = keys;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (List.get(position).getType().equals("Photo"))
    {
        return TYPE_POST_PHOTO;
    }
    else
        {
            return TYPE_TEXT;
        }

    //return super.getItemViewType(position);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    View view;

    if (viewType == TYPE_POST_PHOTO)
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.all_posts_layout, parent, false);
        return new PostAdapter.viewHolder(view);
    }
    else
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.all_user_status_layout, parent, false);
        return new PostAdapter.sviewHolder(view);

    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final String PostKey = keyList.get(position);
    CurrentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_POST_PHOTO)
    {
        ((viewHolder)holder).photoPostMethod(List.get(position),  keyList.get(position));
    } else {

        ((sviewHolder) holder).statusPostMethod(List.get(position), keyList.get(position));

    }

    GlobalPostKey = PostKey;

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return List.size();
}



public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView PostImage;
    CircleImageView PostProfileimage;
    TextView PostUserName;
    TextView PostDate;
    TextView PostTime;
    TextView PostDescription;
    ImageButton LikePostButton, CommentPostButton, SharePostButton;
    TextView DisplayNoOfLikes;
    TextView DisplayNoOfComments;
    TextView DisplayNoOfShare;

    int countLikes, countComments, countShares;

    public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        PostImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        PostProfileimage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_profile_image);
        PostUserName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_user_name);
        PostDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_date);
        PostTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_time);
        PostDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_description);
        LikePostButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_button);
        CommentPostButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_button);
        SharePostButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.share_button);
        DisplayNoOfLikes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.display_no_of_likes);
        DisplayNoOfComments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.display_no_of_comments);
        DisplayNoOfShare = itemView.findViewById(R.id.display_no_of_share);

        LikesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");
    }

    public void setLikesButtonStatus(final String PostKey) {
        LikesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(PostKey).hasChild(CurrentUserID)) {
                        countLikes = (int) dataSnapshot.child(PostKey).getChildrenCount();
                        LikePostButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
                        DisplayNoOfLikes.setText((Integer.toString(countLikes) + (" Likes")));
                    } else {
                        countLikes = (int) dataSnapshot.child(PostKey).getChildrenCount();
                        LikePostButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.dislike);
                        DisplayNoOfLikes.setText((Integer.toString(countLikes) + (" Likes")));
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void setCommentButtonStatus() {

        CommentsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("Comments")) {
                    countComments = (int) dataSnapshot.child("Comments").getChildrenCount();
                    DisplayNoOfComments.setText(Integer.toString(countComments) + " Comments");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void setShareButtonStatus(final String PostKey) {

        ShareRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(PostKey).exists()) {
                    countShares = (int) dataSnapshot.child(PostKey).getChildrenCount();
                    DisplayNoOfShare.setText(Integer.toString(countShares) + " Shares");
                } else {

                    DisplayNoOfShare.setText("0 Shares");

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void photoPostMethod(final Posts posts, final String myPostskey)
    {
        LikesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");
        CommentsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(myPostskey);
        ShareRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Shares");

        Picasso.get().load(posts.getPostimage()).placeholder(R.drawable.photo).into(PostImage);
        Picasso.get().load(posts.getProfileimage()).fit().into(PostProfileimage);
        PostUserName.setText(posts.getFullname());
        PostDate.setText(posts.getDate());
        PostTime.setText(posts.getTime());
        PostDescription.setText(posts.getDescription());

        tobevisitprofileId = posts.getUid();



        PostUserName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                            Intent visitprofileIntent = new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class);
                            visitprofileIntent.putExtra("currentprofileid", tobevisitprofileId);
                            context.startActivity(visitprofileIntent);

            }
        });


        setLikesButtonStatus(myPostskey);
        setCommentButtonStatus();
        setShareButtonStatus(myPostskey);
        final String postDescription = posts.getDescription();
        final String postImage = posts.getPostimage();

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent clickpostintent = new Intent(context, ClickPostActivity.class);
                clickpostintent.putExtra("PostKey", myPostskey);
                context.startActivity(clickpostintent);
                
            }
        });

        CommentPostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent commentsIntent = new Intent(context, CommentsActivity.class);
                commentsIntent.putExtra("PostKey", myPostskey);
                context.startActivity(commentsIntent);
            }
        });

        LikePostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LikeChecker = true;

                LikesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (LikeChecker == true) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.child(myPostskey).hasChild(CurrentUserID)) {
                                LikesRef.child(myPostskey).child(CurrentUserID).removeValue();
                                LikeChecker = false;
                            } else {
                                LikesRef.child(myPostskey).child(CurrentUserID).setValue(true);
                                LikeChecker = false;
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
       SharePostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ShareChecker = true;

                ShareRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (ShareChecker == true) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.child(myPostskey).hasChild(CurrentUserID)) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "You have shared once.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                // ShareRef.child(PostKey).child(CurrentUserID).removeValue();
                                ShareChecker = false;
                            } else {
                                ShareRef.child(myPostskey).child(CurrentUserID).setValue(true);
                                ShareChecker = false;
                            }
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


                Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(postImage);

                Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
                whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, postDescription);
                whatsappIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);
                whatsappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                whatsappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

                try {
                    //context.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(whatsappIntent, "Select an App to share With:"));

                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "No supported app exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}


public class sviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private CircleImageView Profileimage;
    private TextView FullName;
    private TextView Date,Time;
    private TextView UserStatus;

    ImageButton LikeBtn,CommentBtn,ShareBtn;
    TextView   DisplayStatusLikes,DisplayStatusComments, DisplayStatusShare;

    int countLikes , countComments, countShares;

    public sviewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

        Profileimage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_profile_image);
        FullName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_user_name);
        Date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_date);
        Time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_time);
        UserStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_user_status);

        LikeBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_like_button);
        CommentBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_comment_button);
        ShareBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_share_button);

        DisplayStatusLikes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_display_no_of_likes);
        DisplayStatusComments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_display_no_of_comments);
        DisplayStatusShare = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_display_no_of_share);


    }

    public void setStatusLikesButtonStatus(final String statusId)
    {
        SLikesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(statusId).hasChild(CurrentUserID)) {
                        countLikes = (int) dataSnapshot.child(statusId).getChildrenCount();
                        LikeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
                        DisplayStatusLikes.setText((Integer.toString(countLikes) + (" Likes")));
                    } else {
                        countLikes = (int) dataSnapshot.child(statusId).getChildrenCount();
                        LikeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.dislike);
                        DisplayStatusLikes.setText((Integer.toString(countLikes) + (" Likes")));
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void setCommentStatusButtonStatus() {

        SCommentRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("Comments")) {
                    countComments = (int) dataSnapshot.child("Comments").getChildrenCount();
                    DisplayStatusComments.setText(Integer.toString(countComments) + " Comments");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void setStatusShareButtonStatus(final String statusId) {

        SshareRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(statusId).exists()) {
                    countShares = (int) dataSnapshot.child(statusId).getChildrenCount();
                    DisplayStatusShare.setText(Integer.toString(countShares) + " Shares");
                } else {

                    DisplayStatusShare.setText("0 Shares");

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void statusPostMethod(Posts status, final String statusPostKey)
    {
      final String CurrentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        SCommentRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(statusPostKey);
        SLikesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("StatLikes");
        SshareRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("StatShares");


        Picasso.get().load(status.getProfileimage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(Profileimage);
        FullName.setText(status.getFullname());
        Date.setText(status.getDate());
        Time.setText(status.getTime());
        UserStatus.setText(status.getUserstatus());
        statusUserID = status.getUid();

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(status.backgrounduri);
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(image);
            UserStatus.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        int status_color = (int) status.getTextcolor();
        UserStatus.setTextColor(status_color);
        int Text_Size = (int)  status.getTextsize()/ 3 ;
        UserStatus.setTextSize(Text_Size);

        setStatusLikesButtonStatus(statusPostKey);
        setCommentStatusButtonStatus();
        setStatusShareButtonStatus(statusPostKey);

        tobevisitprofileId = status.getUid();

        final String UserStatusforshare = status.getUserstatus();

        FullName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                            Intent visitprofileIntent = new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class);
                            visitprofileIntent.putExtra("currentprofileid", tobevisitprofileId);
                            context.startActivity(visitprofileIntent);
            }
        });

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent clickpostintent = new Intent(context, DeleteStatusActivity.class);
                clickpostintent.putExtra("StatusKey", statusPostKey);
                context.startActivity(clickpostintent);
                //Toast.makeText(context, ""+statusPostKey, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


        CommentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent commentsIntent = new Intent(context, StatCommentActivity.class);
                commentsIntent.putExtra("StatusKey", statusPostKey);
                context.startActivity(commentsIntent);

                // Toast.makeText(context, ""+StatusId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        LikeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LikeChecker = true;

                SLikesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (LikeChecker == true) {

                            if (dataSnapshot.child(statusPostKey).hasChild(CurrentUserId))
                            {
                                SLikesRef.child(statusPostKey).child(CurrentUserId).removeValue();
                                LikeChecker = false;
                            }
                            else {
                                SLikesRef.child(statusPostKey).child(CurrentUserId).setValue(true);
                                LikeChecker = false;
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });


         ShareBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ShareChecker = true;

                SshareRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (ShareChecker == true) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.child(statusPostKey).hasChild(CurrentUserId)) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "You have shared once.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                // ShareRef.child(PostKey).child(CurrentUserID).removeValue();
                                ShareChecker = false;
                            } else {
                                SshareRef.child(statusPostKey).child(CurrentUserId).setValue(true);
                                ShareChecker = false;
                            }
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });



                Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
                whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, UserStatusforshare);
                whatsappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                whatsappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

                try {
                    //   context.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(whatsappIntent, "Select an App to share With:"));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "No supported app exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

**Now I need to manage the above given custom adapter with asynctask where do I need to create Asynctaks for this costum adapter, for querying the database I have created one as you can see.... Please help me if you can, Thanks to everyone in advance!**

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **almost 700 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion sir, but if I remove some codes it will affect the solution. Anyway, can you manage a normal adapter with Asynctask... That will help!